# Where can I find the Dropbox log files?

Tags: debian, dropbox

I am running Dropbox on a Debian server. Once I start Dropbox using

```
python dropbox.py start
```

it stops working after a while and

```
python dropbox.py status
```

reports:

> Dropbox isn't running!

I have no clue why it stops working, all I see is that while running it consumes up to 100% of the CPU.

So I was wondering: Are there any Dropbox log files and if so, where can I find them?

Comment: could you check in ~/.dropbox/logs

Comment: seems like they are encoded or in a binary format?

Comment: @UeliHofstetter did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Anyone get an answer to this?

Comment: I would advise to follow this lead:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198782/why-does-dropbox-say-killed-on-arch-linux Looking into this with `strace` would provide some feedback.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-and-run-dropbox-from-a-headless-linux-server/) you could install the Dropbox daemon as a system service, which then logs into journalctl.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the Dropbox log file location but the following workaround maybe useful.

Check your locale by the following command:

```
$ sudo locale

LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_IN
LC_CTYPE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Your locale maybe any result other than the above.
As dopbox doesn't work well with some specific locales try to change it to another one preferably en_US.UTF-8 or en_GB.UTF-8

To find available locale on you system try the following command:

```
$ sudo locale a
```

And to change the locale use the following command:

```
$ sudo update-locale LANG=LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE
OR
$ sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

After successful start maybe you could change back to your desired locale.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox may be logging into the `/tmp` folder by default, and when navigating there, you may see files with a name like `dropbox-antifreeze-Z8o8vO` in that location.

In my experience, the contents of that log file may only indicate the startup/exit status of the `dropboxd` process, and other log information appears to be something that's not written to disk, but is communicated to the `dropbox.py` script when it communicates with the `dropboxd` process through the socket file at `~/.dropbox/command_socket`